# Telegram Core API messages.search

Tags: c#, api, telegram

Anyone has experience using core telegram API for method messages.search?
https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.search What is the parameter q (text search value), and also filter (MessageFilter) ? I try to create function but the result is Can't decode packet, An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.

I am using https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp, and add this method in my application

Please anyone have the experience to call this method!

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code to TLSharp for the Search method :

the q parameter is the search query.

```
        public async Task<TLAbsMessages> Search(TLAbsInputPeer peer, string q, int offset, int limit)
    {
        if (!IsUserAuthorized())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Authorize user first!");

        var req = new TeleSharp.TL.Messages.TLRequestSearch()
        {
            Peer = peer,
            Q = q,
            Offset = offset,
            Filter = new TLInputMessagesFilterPhotos(),
            Limit = limit
        };
        return await SendRequestAsync<TLAbsMessages>(req);
    }
```